# Is the language $(a^n)^mb^n$ context free?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

$(a^n)^mb^n$  for $m,n\ge 1$
This can be rewritten as $a^{nm}b^n   $

i.e. number of $a$'s is a multiple of number of $b$'s, or for every m $a$'s there is one $b$. I thnk this language can be accepted by NPDA. For every m $a$'s one a can be pushed into the stack, and similarly one can be popped on encountering a $b$. But the NPDA needs to try this for every possible m, where m varies from 1 to maximum string length of $a$'s.

Comment: How would it work with only finite number of states?

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz I thought that since a similar problem for finding m exists for the language $ww^R$ where m in this case is the number of characters after which the NPDA has to begin the reverse string comparison by popping out symbols from the stack; so, since the above language is CFL, this might qualify as one too.

Comment: For $ww^r$ there are finite number of transitions that do something to the stack. What you propose requires infinite number of transitions for every $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty of trying every possible $m$ is, in fact, insurmountable. That language is not context-free.

For the sake of contradiction, assume it is context-free. Let $p$ be [its pumping length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages#Formal_statement). Consider the word $a^{p^2p}b^{p^2}$. I will let you take it from here.